# What is the best anti virus for kali linux?

Tags: antivirus, kali-linux

Since using kali linux I've never really used one as i thought maybe it's built in....?

Comment: As Kali is just Linux then any Linux compatible one? I'm sure someone on here will suggest one. I have to admit I haven't bothered on Kali as it's being used to pentest and an antivirus installed could cause issues for me (catching things I am doing on purpose as part of the pen test)

Comment: I didn't think of that good point

Comment: If you're asking for a product recommendation, that's off-topic. If you're asking if antivirus on Linux is generally a good idea, that's most likely a duplicate.

Comment: I was initionally asking for a producting recommendation yes...but seeing as you guys have basically all told me its pointless as its a pentesting os...ill stick to just keeping updated ect

Comment: @SupaLemonHaze Then it's off-topic. Possible duplicates would be [Should I get an antivirus for Ubuntu?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63097/) and [Do Linux systems need antivirus against ransomware?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/144466). Note also that the takeaway from the answers really isn't to just keep using kali as a general purpose distro. It's not intended that way, and shouldn't be used like that (if that is actually the case, or why that is the case might be on-topic questions).

Answer (score 6):

Kali is mainly for pentesting. It is not supposed to be used as "desktop distro". As far as I know, there is no antivirus and because of tons of exploits built-in you would destroy the whole distro by just installing it.

I would recommend to used it like:

1. Install, Update, Setup, Image then
2. Do a pentest / reimage,
3. Update, Image if updated
4. do a pentest reimage.
5. Update, Image if updated

... Go for Debian for normal use. Kali is based on it. But if you are beginner, I would recommend Ubuntu rather.

Regarding AV, use what @Matt Spaulding recommended

Comment: +1 you really shouldn't be using kali in any other way. If you want to add a source for the first claim, it's also in the official [kali documentation](http://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux). Note also that the default user in kali is the root user, which isn't very secure. Installing clamav shouldn't destroy kali, but actually running it may impact the functionality of some tools.

Comment: Id say I'm a begginer although i'm learning a lot, call me a script kiddie if you wish haha.... i like diving in the deep end...i actually use kali as my desktop.

Comment: From the answers ive recieved, id not like any things messed up in kali...i run root and non root using wireshark...so i guess ill keep it without. Thanks.

Comment: @Fis agree using AV on Kali can cause issues and will disrupt what can be achieved with it

Comment: @SupaLemonHaze I would recommend to install another distro and use Kali in virtual for learning. It has many advantages. Except it does need to work well with some hardware used ie to capture Wifi traffic. I also would recommend to stop smoking weed ;)

Comment: I totally agree i should but i really like kali linux as my main...i have it alongside linux mint 18 Sarah but much prefer kali...i even have it on my laptop :) my next venture is to start learning how to ssh into my laptop from my desktop and visa-versa...Thanks for the advice but i havent smoked weed for a long time ;) i'm just really crap at making usernames and i thought it was cool...guess i failed there then haha

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best known antivirus for Linux is [ClamAV](https://www.clamav.net).  If you want to have antivirus that's what I would suggest that you use.  You should probably have a rootkit checker as well, something like [RKHunter](http://rkhunter.sourceforge.net/) or similar.  There are other AV vendors that have Linux antivirus solutions like Kaspersky but that is a commercial solution and not included with Kali.